# ImportError: No module named base in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Spyder IDE. I am running a script once and everything is ok. I run it a second time and appears the error. In my script I use the following packages:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize
import cProfile
from sympy import solve,exp
from sympy.abc import y
from PIL import Image
import dicom
from bisect import bisect_left,bisect_right
import math
import os
import seaborn as sns
import scipy
import pandas
```

I don't know If has anything to do with the packages but I cannot fix it.
Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-a431862ce876>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/dkoimt0/Spyder/swse.py', wdir='/Users/dkoimt0/Spyder')

File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell
/sitecusto  mize.py", line 588, in runfile__umr__.run(verbose=verbose)

 File "/Applications/Spyder-   Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 538, in run
modpath = getattr(module, '__file__', None)

File "/Users/dkoimt0/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/external/six.py", line 117, in __getattr__
value = getattr(_module, attr)

File "email/__init__.pyc", line 79, in __getattr__

ImportError: No module named base
```

Comment: Do you have a (broken?) package named `email` in your working directory? It looks like Python may be finding that instead of the standard library's `email` module.